# How to overwrite file via java nio writer?

Tags: java, io, nio, java-io

I try files writer as follows:

```
String content = "Test File Content";
```

- I used as like : `Files.write(path, content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);`

If file is not create, file is created and content is written. But If file available , the file content is `Test File ContentTest File Content` and if the code is run repeat, the file content is `Test File ContentTest File ContentTest File Content` ...

- I used as like : `Files.write(path, content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);` ,

If file is not create, file is created and than thow an exception as follow:

> java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException:
>   /home/gyhot/Projects/indexing/ivt_new/target/test-classes/test_file
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:88)
>     at
>   ...

How to overwrite file via java new I/O?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You want to call the method without any `OpenOption` arguments.

```
Files.write(path, content.getBytes());
```

From the Javadoc:

> The options parameter specifies how the the file is created or opened.
>   If no options are present then this method works as if the `CREATE`,
>   `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, and `WRITE` options are present. In other words, it
>   opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or
>   initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of `0`

Answer (score 53):

You want to use both [StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#TRUNCATE_EXISTING) and StandardOpenOption.CREATE options together:

```
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(),
         StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
         StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING );
```